# How to plot DOM [Depth of Market ] in Tradingview chart

Tags: pine-script, trading

I want to create a indicator which will plot DOM i.e. Depth of Market in tradingview.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done for now. Scripts don't have access to DOM info yet, not even to bid/ask volume. Perhaps one day.